# How to extract System.Reflection.PropertyInfo names of a class object as first row of a csv file

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, getproperties

I'm trying to use System.Reflection to output a first row of column header information for a csv text file before I create the actual generic List from my data source.

```
public class DocMetaData
{
    public const string SEPARATOR = "\t";       // horizontal tab is delimiter
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string DocClass { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Folder { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}
```

In the following routine, I am trying to loop through the properties of the object definition and use the property name as a "column name" for my first row of my output file:

```
private void OutputColumnNamesAsFirstLine(StreamWriter writer)
    {
        StringBuilder md = new StringBuilder();
        PropertyInfo[] columns;
        columns = typeof(DocMetaData).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                      BindingFlags.Static);
        foreach (var columnName in columns)
        {
            md.Append(columnName.Name); md.Append(DocMetaData.SEPARATOR);
        }
        writer.WriteLine(md.ToString());
    }
```

The foreach loop exits immediately. Also, I put a constant separator in the class but I want to use that as a field separator value (rather than as a "column" name).

I am assuming that the ordinal position of the properties in the class will be maintained consistently if I can get something like this to work.

The remainder of the code which creates the `List<DocMetaData>` from my data source works but I'd like to add this "first row" stuff.

Thank you for help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have to do

```
columns = typeof(DocMetaData).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                      BindingFlags.Instance);
```

The fields you are trying to search are `instance` fields not `static`

Comment: You are wonderful to help me. Thanks very much - worked beautifully.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `BindingFlags.Static` because that yields only static members (public static).  Use `BindingFlag.Instance` instead, since your properties are instance members.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `BindingFlags.Static` with BindingFlags.Instance`. The properties in your`DocMetaData` are not static.

```
private void OutputColumnNamesAsFirstLine(StreamWriter writer)
{
    StringBuilder md = new StringBuilder();
    PropertyInfo[] columns;
    columns = typeof(DocMetaData).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                  BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var columnName in columns)
    {
        md.Append(columnName.Name); 
        md.Append(DocMetaData.SEPARATOR);
    }
    writer.WriteLine(md.ToString());
}
```